# How to deploy all Supabase edge functions at once?

Tags: supabase

I have multiple Supabase edge functions I want to deploy simultaneously when I push to production. These are all the functions in my `.supabase/functions` folder, ie:

```
.supabase
    functions
        my_function_1
            index.ts
        my_function_2
            index.ts
        ...
```

The [Supabase CLI docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/cli/supabase-functions-deploy) explain how to deploy a single function with `supabase functions deploy <Function name> [flags]`, but don't seem to mention deploying all of them together.

Do I have to run the deploy command once for each function? For ex:

```
supabase functions deploy my_function_1 && supabase functions deploy my_function_2
```

Or is there a simpler way?

I tried simply running `supabase functions deploy` but got this error indicating that I need to pass a function name as an arg:

```
Error: accepts 1 arg(s), received 0
Usage:
  supabase functions deploy <Function name> [flags]
```

The firebase functions equivalent would be `firebase deploy --only functions` ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment))

Comment: Locally you can use `supabase functions serve --all` for deploying all with a single command I would use a bash/python script that reads that folder and deploy each function.

Comment: @Mansueli thanks for the suggestion. I do have a custom deploy script, I just wish it came built-in to supabase

Comment: I've answered this question now that it is possible directly with the CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **[now](https://github.com/supabase/cli/pull/1111)** possible to deploy all functions to a linked project in Supabase:

Just run this:

```
supabase functions deploy
```

You can also set parameters (that will be used on all deployments):

```
supabase functions deploy --import-map import_map.json  --no-verify-jwt  --project-ref xxsupanachoxx
```